# How to resize canvas image(base64) using jQuery without losing quality?

Tags: canvas, html5-video, video-capture, image-resizing

Currently, i'm trying to take snapshot from  `<video>` , the preview res is 320*420. I want to double the res so the result will bigger . When try to resize, the result is blurry. Is there any library should i implement?

**HTML**

```
<style>
#videoframe{
   border: 10px solid black;
   height:320px;
   margin-bottom:20px; 
   width:420px;
   padding:0;
   overflow:hidden;
   position:relative;
}
</style>

<div class="col-lg-6" id="videoframe">
          <video style="margin:0;width: 100%; height:100%;" id="player" webkit-playsinline="true" autoplay playsinline>
           </video>
   </div> 
   <canvas id="c" width="320"height="420" ></canvas>
```

**JS**

```
function imageToDataUri(img, width, height) {

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

    return canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1.0);
}
$("#btnCapture").click(function () {  
        videoPlayer.pause();
        
        var canvas = document.getElementById("c")
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(videoPlayer, 0,0 ,320, 420);
        image = canvas.toDataURL('image/png',1.0);

        //Resize
        var img = new Image;
        img.onload = resizeImage;
        img.src = image;

        function resizeImage() {
            var newDataUri = imageToDataUri(this, 640, 840);
            //NewDataUri is final result
        }
});
```

Comment: Why can't `ctx.drawImage(videoPlayer, 0,0 ,320, 420);` draw a bigger size?

Comment: what do you mean with your question  @VC.One? draw a bigger size is possible but it's just blurry .

Comment: What is resolution of the input video? I meant why not draw big then scale down (=crisp), instead of drawing small and then trying to scale that up (=blurry)... `ctx.drawImage(videoPlayer, 0,0 , actualVideoWidth, actualVideoHeight);`.

Answer (score 0):

By default the CanvasRenderingContext2D's `drawImage()` method applies some sort of interpolation e.g. nearest-neighbor or bilinear while drawing the given source. Luckily you can disable this behaviour by setting the `.imageSmoothingEnabled` property to false before drawing something.

For example:

```js
function imageToDataUri(img, width, height) {

  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  canvas.getContext('2d').imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

  return canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1.0);
}

let image = new Image();
image.crossOrigin = "anonymous"
image.onload = (e) => {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("c")
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(e.target, 0, 0, e.target.naturalWidth, e.target.naturalHeight);
}
image.src = "https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy?quest=https://picsum.photos/id/237/320/420"
document.getElementById("btnCapture").addEventListener("click", (e) => {

  var canvas = document.getElementById("c")
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  image = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1.0);

  //Resize
  var img = new Image;
  img.onload = resizeImage;
  img.src = image;

  function resizeImage() {
    var newDataUri = imageToDataUri(this, 640, 840);
    let img = new Image();
    img.src = newDataUri;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
    let anchor = document.createElement("a");
    anchor.href = newDataUri;
    anchor.download = "capture.png";
    anchor.click();
  }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="320" height="420"></canvas>
<input type="button" id="btnCapture" value="capture">
```

Comment: should i use .imageSmoothingEnabled property only for resize (second draw image)? or should i implement it for the first draw image too?

Comment: Yes, only for the resize.